# iPhone - How do i get direction with degree based location

Tags: iphone, ios, cllocationmanager

First I've implemented location manager functions in my class and whict are working fine, and gives me the current location. From that location I got how to get location degrees from [here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/getting-your-location-in-an-iphone-application). but I'm not able to get the direction (i.e. North, South, East, West) I've referred [this](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/42992-how-do-i-make-compass.html) too. I want the location that I'm getting to be displayed in degrees with direction format like [this](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html). i.e. location manager gives me +37.33019332,-122.02298792 and i want something like 37° 19' 49"**N**, -122° 1' 23"**E**. I'm getting all things just don't know how to get the last "N" and "E".
If i use `CLLocation.course` for this I'm getting my direction course.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually very simple. Latitudes begin at 0° at the equator with the north pole being 90.0 and the south pole being -90.0. Basically, if the latitude is between 0 and 90, you're in the northern hemisphere and the southern hemisphere for latitude between 0 and -90.

Longitude basically works the same way. 0° refers to the prime meridian which is the imaginary line that runs through Greenwich, England and a part of Africa. A positive longitude up to 180° refers to locations east of the prime meridian, while negative longitudes refer to areas west of the prime meridian up to 180°.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code and put CLLocationManagerDelegate at .h file

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading
{             
    updatedHeading = newHeading.magneticHeading;
    float headingFloat = 0 - newHeading.magneticHeading;

    rotateImg.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(headingFloat*radianConst);    
    float value = updatedHeading;
    if(value >= 0 && value < 23)
    {
        compassFault.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f° N",value];
    }
    else if(value >=23 && value < 68)
    {
        compassFault.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f° NE",value];
    }
    else if(value >=68 && value < 113)
    {
        compassFault.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f° E",value];
    }
    else if(value >=113 && value < 185)
    {
        compassFault.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f° SE",value];
    }
    else if(value >=185 && value < 203)
    {
        compassFault.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f° S",value];
    }
    else if(value >=203 && value < 249)
    {
        compassFault.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f° SE",value];
    }
    else if(value >=249 && value < 293)
    {
        compassFault.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f° W",value];
    }
    else if(value >=293 && value < 350)
    {
        compassFault.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f° NW",value];
    }
  }
```

Comment: this will return compass direction. i don't need that. anyways thanks for all your help.

Comment: @Nims But this one is incorrect since it returns NULL for 0 to 360 degree value..