# Swift/iPhone - How do you tell which hemisphere you are in?

Tags: iphone, swift, core-location

As angles of latitude return similar numbers for both the northern or southern hemispheres how do you tell from the CoreLocation latitudes which hemisphere you are in?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624481/iphone-how-do-i-get-direction-with-degree-based-location may i help you.

Comment: Latitudes range 0-90 degrees in both hemispheres, which is why they are qualified with a North or South. It appears CoreLocation returns a negative number when in the Southern hemisphere. Many thanks.

Comment: Follow AbecedarioPoint's link for the solution.